# Ленивая инциализация при помощи прокси класса

Tags: рефлексия, c#

Доброго времени суток! Имеется следующая задача: необходимо поля помеченные своим атрибутом,  при помощи рефлексии проинициализировать. По сути, мне надо создать прокси класс, который будет перехватывать любой вызов от объекта, и сразу же создавать инстанс! Пробовал с Castle Dynamic Proxy - не вышло! Какие ещё решения можете предложить?

Answer (score 1):

Не обязательно. Я бы сделал базовый класс, конструктор которого инициализирует поля.

Примерно так:

```
foreach (var fi in this.GetFields(BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance))
{
  if (!fi.IsDefined(typeof(MyAttribute), false))
    continue;

  var att = fi.GetCustomAttributes(typeof(MyAttribute), false)[0] as MyAttribute;
  fi.SetValue(this, att.Value);
}
```

Только это не ленивая инициализация. Ленивую инициализацию надо делать в геттере свойства. Для облегчения можно было бы опять-таки использовать какой-нибудь метод базового класса.

Comment: Собственно всё вышеописанное у меня есть, нужна ленивая инициализация, то есть закидывать в SetValue прокси класс, а не инстанс самого класса.

Comment: при том что залазить внутрь и какбы то нибыло дополнять классы которые хочу инциализировать, я не могу

Comment: Тогда в базовом классе нужно сделать методы - аксессоры для реализации свойств, которые кэшируют во внутреннем словаре значения свойств, а если ещё не закэшировано - вызывают переданный делегат и кэшируют результат его выполнения. Примерно с такой сигнатурой:

protected TPropertyType GetPropertyValue<TPropertyType>(string propertyName, Func<TPropertyType> accessor);

Если хотите контроль над именем свойства на этапе компиляции, передавайте его в виде лямбда-выражения. Тогда первый параметр будет иметь тип Expression<Func<TPropertyType>>, а передаваться туда будет ()=>this.CurrentProperty.